# Spring security predefined login page not displaying?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am following the Spring Security tutorial from this url http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

As per Step 6 my app is redirected to

```
     http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/spring_security_login
```

So the predefined Spring Security authentication page should be rendered but I am getting an error "Requested resource is not available". Am I missing something?

Comment: Check your logs to see if the server started successfully. If it did, what is the URL displayed in your browser's address bar?

Comment: thanks for the reply, the mvc runs fine. It's d security framework which is not displaying the default page. The app is redirected to
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/spring_security_login. After this d browser shows an error resource not available

Comment: What application container are you running on (i.e. Tomcat, Jetty, WebSphere, etc)?